Issue with static files in laravel and nginx behind aws network loadbalancer and api gateway
I have problem with my generated static files from documentation package (scribe) in Laravel.
They are try to be served from private dns.
Some part of my trafic goes through AWS Api Gateway to Network load balancer to forward it (base on prefix) to app mesh where is passed to envoy proxy (side car) to ECS service where is nginx with php-fpm.
All my Laravel endpoint works, however it seems like there is issue with files from public directory. I get lost in all these up streams and downstreams is anybody able to help?
Here there is api integration to NLB. (AWS CDK TypeScript)
const nlbIntegration = new apigateway.Integration({
            type: apigateway.IntegrationType.HTTP_PROXY,
            integrationHttpMethod: 'ANY',
            uri: `http://${nlbDns}/{proxy}`,
            options: {
                connectionType: apigateway.ConnectionType.VPC_LINK,
                vpcLink: vpcLink,
                requestParameters: {
                    'integration.request.path.proxy': 'method.request.path.proxy'
                },
            },
        });

And app mesh gateway for service: (AWS CDK TypeScript)
appmesh.virtualGateway.addGatewayRoute('core-service', {
        routeSpec: GatewayRouteSpec.http({
          routeTarget: coreService.virtualService,
          match: {
            path: HttpGatewayRoutePathMatch.startsWith('/'.concat(serviceConfig?.host_name ?? 'core').concat('/')),
            rewriteRequestHostname: true,
          },
        }),
      })

Nginx conf below:
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /var/www/html/public;
        
        fastcgi_cache dwchiang;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 204 60m;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache $http_authorization $cookie_laravel_session;
        fastcgi_cache_lock on;
        fastcgi_cache_lock_timeout 10s;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 6144;

        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        fastcgi_pass            127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index           index.php;
        fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param           HTTPS $fastcgi_param_https_variable;
        fastcgi_read_timeout    900s;
        include                 fastcgi_params;
    }

I tried to remove apigateway and make NLB public - in this case docs from Laravel worked fine, however it needs to be hidden after the api gateway.

I stuck into same problem with nova. My resolution - deploy static assets separately - some cdn, for example - and change ASSET_URL to this cdn.

Thank you for the offer, it solves the problem to some extent.
Isn't there some correct way to configure up&down streams to make it work without cdn?
